# How to call procedure wrapped up in package

Tags: sql

I need to manually call the procedure PROC_ENTRY_TIME for loading fresh data into TABLE_ENTRY_TIME. How do I do that?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PK_ENTRY_TIME IS
PROCEDURE PROC_ENTRY_TIME
AS
BEGIN
    execute immediate 'truncate table TABLE_ENTRY_TIME';
    insert into TABLE_ENTRY_TIME 
        SELECT  TABLE_CASE.ID_NUMBER , max( TABLE_ACT_ENTRY.ENTRY_TIME )
        FROM  SA.TABLE_CASE TABLE_CASE 
            INNER JOIN  SA.TABLE_ACT_ENTRY   TABLE_ACT_ENTRY
            ON  TABLE_CASE.OBJID = TABLE_ACT_ENTRY.ACT_ENTRY2CASE
     commit;
END  PROC_ENTRY_TIME;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer:

```
begin
    pk_entry_time.proc_entry_time;
end;
/
```